# Showing a polygon on map, and zooming until it fits with OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

If I dynamically render a polygon (for example the border of a district in the UK) on a map, with OpenLayers 3, is it possible somehow to zoom in on the polygon, until it exactly fits the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ever guarantee to *exactly* fit the view as in general your district may have a different aspect ratio (width/height) than your view.

OpenLayers 3 provides the useful [`fit`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#fit) method on the view to allow you to do this.